# How to create sequential ID's per user in Postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I'm trying to create a table in postgresql to hold user Work Items. Each Work Item will have a unique ID across the system, but then will also have a friendly sequential ID for that specific user.

So far I have been just using:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkItems
(
  Id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);
```

but I don't know how to compartmentalize this serial per user, nor how to do it with sequences either.

So I want for users to see sequential Friendly Ids

```
User1: ids = 1, 2, 3 etc..
User2: ids = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..
```

and not have to deal with the unique Ids, but those items would have unique ids from 1-8.

I've looked around quite a bit and can't find any posts on this topic. Maybe it's just hard to specify and search for?

Should I be storing the LastWorkIdUsed in a user column, and then just manually create a friendly Id for their items? Seems like I'd unnecessarily have to worry about concurrency and transactions then. Is there an easy way to pass the LastWorkIdUsed per user to Postgresql when generating a number?

Or is there a way to assign a sequence to a user?

Perhaps I've got the fundamental design idea wrong. How would one do this in SQLServer or MySQL also?

Comment: You have to execute a SELECT statement to retrieve the MAX value of WorkItem WHERE user is the specified user.  Then add 1 to it, and that becomes your new User/Workitem number.

Comment: There's no such thing as a friendly ID. If users are seeing ID numbers, I guarantee they're not going to care about whether they're sequential or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You forgot about all the table locking nonsense that is needed to make that approach work. Unless there will never be more than one connection to the database at a time so you don't have to worry about race conditions.

Comment: @muistooshort: Unless there are two users having the same user ID, I don't see how there could be any race conditions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: So each user is guaranteed to only have one connection at a time? I actually find the *user* terminology quite ambiguous here: database user? application user? some other type of user? I'd guess that this is a job for `row_number() over (...)` but I can't see what the real intent is.

Comment: @muistooshort: Seriously?  What's the likelihood that a user is creating two work items on two different connections *at the same exact moment?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes. Software history is littered with the corpses of "impossible" things, the "impossible" happens pretty much every day in software.

Comment: Well I'm accessing this database from an ASP.NET MVC web service. For now the service is the sole db connection, but can't it handle multiple connections at a time? The web client is a licensed desktop app, which I suppose I could somehow limit to running 1 instance at a time. But it could still bombard the server with 2 requests that could be processed simultaneously, no?
Perhaps Chris Hayes had the best solution, which is that users just won't care... I thought maybe this would be easy.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you *also* have a globally unique key. You can use that to solve your concurrency issues. If you allow the user work item number to be null, you can first create the work item, then do something like this to assign it a "friendly" number.  (T-SQL dialect, @workItemID is the globally unique ID):

```
Update wi
set friendlyNumber = coalesce(
    (select max(friendlyNumber)+1 from WorkItem wi2 
     where wi2.userID = wi.userID and not wi2.friendlyNumber is null)
, 1)
From WorkItem wi
where workItemID = @workItemID and friendlyNumber is null
```

Then find out the number like this:

```
select friendlyNumber from WorkItem where workItemID = @workItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to have an auto-generated ID inside a table is the one using a sequence, if the sequence used on a `int`/`bigint` column then I see no reason why this won't be user-friendly.

A demo follows on `Postgresql 13.6` assuming `postgres` is the user under which table and sequence will belong:

- Define a sequence to work with.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq;
ALTER SEQUENCE user_id_seq OWNER TO chopshop;
```

- Test the sequence

```sql
-- This should return 1
SELECT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass);
```

[image]

- Use it as a default value on your table/relation.

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id bigint not null primary key default nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)
  ..
  ..
);
```

- You might need to modify `nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)` to `nextval('public.user_id_seq'::regclass)` (a.k.a prepend your schema name) in some Postgresql versions.

**Can you assign a sequence to a user/entry?**

- You could use a trigger and re-calibrate the sequence before insertion, but please don't.
- That's an anti-pattern
- Use a `reference_number` column instead which will be calculated from your back-end code (Spring, Django, FastAPI, Node, etc) which will follow a pattern for each user.

Answer (score -3):

I feel that this is a "I want the moon" requirement.

If you can explain why you need that kind of ID, it would be much more relevant to us when finding a solution for you.

It appears to me that you want a trail of what a user worked on.

***My solution :*** Is that possible that you've made a design mistake ?

- workitem (id_workitem)
- user (id_user)
- commit (id_user, id_workitem, committed_on, comment)

So now, you just have to join those tables and order by committed_on. And leave (or not) the numbering to your app.

Comment: 5 years later, I no longer need this. From memory I wanted users to have IDs associated with tasks, and wanted those tasks to be sequential according to the user. If I were doing that now I'd use a watermark value for each user to remember their last ID, and have a public friendly ID and a private globally unique table ID. Kinda like what Ben described below.

Comment: As far as I remember, you did not choose an answer as a solution; that's why I answered. You can do what Ben is suggesting. That's a solution : a solution mimicking what's a DBMS is for.